# Cannot find Robocopy error in log file

Tags: robocopy

I have a robocopy .cmd file running on windows 10 64-bit (French version) and I keep getting an error at the end of the log file in the summary section:

```
            Total     Copié    Ignoré    Discordance  ÉCHEC    Extras
 Rép :      3569         1      3567         0         1         0
 Fichiers : 21490        98     21392        0         0         59
 Octets :   3.616 g   13.63 m   3.603 g      0         0        2.53 m
 Heures:   0:00:34   0:00:21                       0:00:00   0:00:12

 Débit :              658152 Octets/sec.
 Débit :              37.659 Méga-octets/min.
```

For those of you unfamiliar with French the above is reporting that robocopy Failed to copy one of the folders. However if I search the file for the value "error" (or in French "erreur") 
nothing is found. Any ideas on how to track down the error would be much appreciated as it is stopping my program terminating correctly. Basically, any errors reported in the summary 
at the end of the log file means that my program terminates with an exception. Usually when this happens I can find the error and take appropriate action such as excluding the file or 
folder in my script if it is not important. However, here I have no idea which folder is failing. My robocopy command has the following switches:

Options : *.* /V /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /XJF /XJD /R:0 /W:0

Please let me know if you require any further information

gauss76